# couldn't connect to server mongodb even after deleting lock file

Tags: php, windows, mongodb

Couldn't connect to server MongoDB even after deleting lock file. We have installed MongoDB on windows machine and accessing it from the another window machine in network.

It is giving below error:

> Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at  src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
>   exception: connect failed

We have also tried to connect after deleting lock file. Can any suggest what will be the wrong there.

Comment: Please check the log file it will give the detail about the failure

Comment: did you check if mongo's even running?

Comment: It is trying to connect on the localhost. The machine you are trying to access from will not likely be able to see this. You will need to try and access Mongo using the IP of the server it is running on.

Comment: restart mongod service... this file contains the process ID and is generate again when you restart mongod service